# Root my Android (Motorola Moto E)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

What is the best method for rooting a Motorola Moto E Android running kitkat 4.4.4? I know nothing about unlocking bootloaders, so any help you could give me there would be great!

Comment: Did you try one ofl those one-click rooting software ? KingoRoot seems better, or iRoot, FramaRoot, etc

Comment: @esQmo Never use a one-click tool on Moto devices, it will frequently brick them.

Comment: @acejavelin Never experienced that! I use KingoRoot and it never resulted in a brick.

Comment: @esQmo I am quite active in various Moto device forums on XDA and have written rooting and other tutorials for several devices..  We have seen King(o)root and other one click methods brick several devices, although this is usually a softbrick only, most users who attempt this method don't know how to recover from that.

Comment: @acejavelin Okay, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Rooting modern Moto devices is quite simple, and there are not many variations.

You must unlock the bootloader using [Moto's Unlock](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a) site. This will give you the pre-requisites needed to root, also be aware this will completely erase all your data

Next download the latest [TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/motorolamotoe.html) for your device (Moto E original model linked) and [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/supersu/).

Flash TWRP, backup, flash SuperSU, reboot. Done, you will be rooted.

For more specific information, XDA is your best source. http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e